# How do I float two divs side-by-side without specifying a width and large amount of data or text?

Tags: html, css

Yet this puts the right div on a new line while the left div expands to the entire width above.

I trying to do side by side by both div but its come newline co

```css
.div-container
 {
  background:#FFC;
  overflow:hidden;
  margin:0 auto;
  width:900px;
 }
 .div1, .div2
 {
  float:left;
 }
```

```html
<div class="div-container">
 <div class="div1">
     <p>
         It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable 
            content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is
            that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters.
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="div2">
     <p>
         Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. 
            Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, 
            when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you can use bootstrap gird, just read this tutorial https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_grid_system.asp

Comment: facing similar issue... thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you dont want to specify width, you should use flex - https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

```
.div-container {
    display: flex;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

```css
.div-container
 {
  background:#FFC;
  overflow:hidden;
  margin:0 auto;
  width:900px;
 }
 .div1, .div2
 {
  float:left;
 }
```

```html
<div class="div-container">
 <div class="div1">
     <p>
         It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable 
            content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is
            that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters.
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="div2">
     <p>
         Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. 
            Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, 
            when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

```css
.div-container {
    background:#FFC;
  overflow:hidden;
  margin:0 auto;
  width:900px;
    display: -webkit-flex; /* Safari */
    display: flex;
}

.div1, .div2  {
    -webkit-flex: 1;  /* Safari 6.1+ */
    -ms-flex: 1;  /* IE 10 */    
    flex: 1;
    padding:5px;
}
.div1 { background:#e5c6ff;}
.div2 { background:#c6fffd;}
```

```html
<div class="div-container">
 <div class="div1">
     <p>
         It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable 
            content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is
            that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters.
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="div2">
     <p>
         Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. 
            Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, 
            when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set **50%** width for every div for example